# Can I upload text file Larger than 16mb to mongodb through post request in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multer

I am building a website where users upload their details and work to the database but their work is a combination of text, videos and images. And I don't know how to upload such file to the mongodb at once with multer. Someone should please help.

I tried uploading it without multer but when a document exceed 16mb it displays an error.

Answer (score 1):

A single MongoDB document can be no more than 16MB. Multer is not the problem here.

Luckily there is a solution to storing large files in MongoDB: [GridFS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/).

The file is broken up into chunks that are smaller than 16MB and then stored in a separate collection. Rather than this:

```
{
  _id: ...,
  name: "John Smith",
  work: [{
    file: (a very large binary file),
    filename: "foo.mp4"
  }]
}
```

You'd save something like this:

1. GridFS will create a document in a collection named, for example ['work.files'](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/#the-files-collection)

```
{
  _id: ...,
  filename: "foo.mp4",
  ...
}
```

2. GridFS will create multiple documents, each smaller than 16MB, in a collection named for example ['work.chunks'](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/gridfs/#the-chunks-collection)

```
{
  _id: ...,
  files_id: (a reference to a work.files._id),
  n: 1,
  data: ...
}, {
  _id: ...,
  files_id: (the same reference to a work.files._id),
  n: 2,
  data: ...
}
```

3. Rather than the embedded file, you store a reference to the entry in `work.files`.

```
{
  _id: ...,
  name: "John Smith",
  work: [{
    _id: (a reference to a work.files._id)
  }]
}
```

You don't need to create these collections by yourself and there's no need to chunk the files up in parts yourself, as there are libraries to help you with this, [such as Mongoose-GridFS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-gridfs). Most libraries provide methods to both stream files into and out of a GridFS collection, so it can be very performant, as well.

For very small files (such as an avatar) it might still be advantageous to store them embedded in your document.

---

A side note: *There's not a lot "special" about GridFS—it's not an extension you need to install but more of a blessed standard that many people follow for interoperability. The documents are stored in standard, normal MongoDB collections. As such you can store any metadata/ custom fields ([example from the previously mentioned library](https://github.com/lykmapipo/mongoose-gridfs/blob/1db97c61c618a027e5a5338de780cc6330141853/src/bucket.js#L105)) in `(whatever).files` if you want. Depending on how large the files you're going to store are & if you're going to stream them (eg. video) you may want to tune chunk size (default 255kb)—even per file.*